# Селектор и массив

Tags: jquery

Стыдно просить такую мелочь, но голова не работает.

```
$("#tableproduct1").on('input focus', function () {
        var price = AddProduct[1][0]['price_products_deal'];
        q = $('.productTableAdd_Q ').val();
        itog = AddProduct[1][0]['itog_products_deal'] = price * q;
        $('#tableproduct1 .productTableAdd_Itog').text(itog);
    });
```

tableproduct1 может быть tableproduct2 и 3,4 
Берется цифра с массива AddProduct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('[id^="tableproduct"]').on('input focus', function () {
  var index = +this.id.replace("tableproduct", ""); 
  var price = AddProduct[index][0]['price_products_deal'];
  ...
```

Но лучше присвойте этим элементам один класс и выбирайте по классу, а индекс положите в `data-index="1"`:

```
  var index = +$(this).data("index");
```

---

> Вопрос. tableproduct может добавляться в процессе в дом дерево

Нужно использовать "делегирование" - когда обработчик события прикрепляется к существующему родительскому элементу с указанием для каких элементов внутри родителя обработчик должен срабатывать.

```
$(document).on('input focusin', '[id^="tableproduct"]', function() {
```

Comment: Вопрос. tableproduct может добавляться в процессе в дом дерево и как правильно отловить изменение

Comment: Извините за оффтоп. = + что значит?

Comment: @axmed2004 Преобразование строки в число: `var num = +"123";`